# is there any way to integrate dwr 3.0 with play?

Tags: java, ajax, playframework, dwr

[DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) is a very good java ajax framework. and it has bean integrate with many frameworks like struts2, spring, hibernate... and many other client ajax frameworks, like dojo, tibco gi, yui....

is there any way to integrate dwr 3.0 with play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably quite difficult. DWR needs a servlet (declared in WEB-INF/web.xml) to handle requests.

Since Play Framework doesn't use servlets, integrating DWR in Play Framework requires:

- To develop a controller to handle requests, emulating the DWR servlet (this part can be very difficult depending on the servlet complexity).
- To routes all DWR requests to this controller.

Answer (score 1):

I integrated DWR with Play using apache at the front webserver. Like for example

http://www.mysite.com/dwr -> Points to DWR
http://www.mysite.com/site -> Points to Play

Then as both sites are in the same domain, cookies are shared and also authentication